# npm install cordova - not installed

Tags: cordova

In my windows machine when I type "npm install -g cordova" command I get an error

```
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

Any idea how to install cordova through windows command line interface?

Comment: Seems to be working ok on my Windows 8.1 VM... what version of Windows are you running, and, are you sure you're hooked up to the internet?

Comment: I am using windows 7, and I am connected to internet.

Comment: What's the output of ```npm -v```? And of ```npm config list```?

Comment: What did npm config list give you?

Answer (score 0):

Look your firewall and another shield and Windows defender. I'm sure 90 %.